Refactor code create cron Magento 2.4.3 to 2.4.7
Old Code:
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Module\Coord\Cron;

class GenerateShipping
{
    protected \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger;

    /**
     * @var \Module\Coord\Model\ShipmentGeneration
     */
    private \Module\Coord\Model\ShipmentGeneration $shipment;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Module\Coord\Model\ShipmentGeneration $shipmentGeneration
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Module\Coord\Model\ShipmentGeneration $shipmentGeneration
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->shipment = $shipmentGeneration;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the cron
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->logger->info("Cronjob GenerateShipping is executed.");
        $this->shipment->ordersToShip();
    }
}


Update Code
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2024
 * All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 * Check module
 * Magento 2.4.7-p3
 */

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Module\Coord\Cron;

use Exception;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Module\Coord\Model\ShipmentGeneration;

/**
 * This class GenerateShipping
 *
 * @class GenerateShipping
 * @since 11/13/2024
 * @version 1.0.0
 */
class GenerateShipping
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param ShipmentGeneration $shipment
     */
    public function __construct(
        protected LoggerInterface $logger,
        private readonly ShipmentGeneration $shipment
    ) {
    }

    /**
     * Execute the cron
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function execute(): void
    {
        $this->shipment->ordersToShip();
        $this->logger->info("Cronjob GenerateShipping is executed.");
    }
}

